# React storybook PostCSS configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook, postcss, postcss-loader

I am setting up a storybook for my React app. I am facing an issue with PostCSS, apparently my storybook configuration does not process PostCSS and my styles are completely ignored.

This is my package.json:

```
{

  ...

  "devDependencies": {

    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.2.8",

    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.2.8",

    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.2.8",

    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",

    "@storybook/react": "^6.2.8",

    "css-loader": "2.1.1",

    "extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin": "4.3.2",

    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",

    "postcss-csso": "^3.0.0",

    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",

    "style-loader": "^2.0.0"

  }

}
```

and this is my main.js:

```
module.exports = {

  "stories": [

    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  ],

  "addons": [

    "@storybook/addon-links",

    "@storybook/addon-essentials",

    "@storybook/addon-postcss"
  ]
}
```

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Hey @luthien, did you get any error? And did you manage to fix it? I'm having some issues related w/ postcss.
`You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders` but my project is VueJS + Nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading `postcss` to version 8:

```js
npm i -D postcss@8
```

and then, replace your current reference to the `@storybook/addon-postcss` inside `main.js` file to this:

```js
{
      name: "@storybook/addon-postcss",
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require("postcss"),
        },
      },
    },
```